# Google maps zoom level migration v2 to v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, migration

I'm migrating a piece of google maps code in javascript from v2 to v3

The following v2 piece shows a map with the center zoomed in, so you can see street names and specific details

```
var mapG = new GMap(document.getElementById("gmmap"));
var point = new GLatLng(52.6461049, 6.5583690);
mapG.centerAndZoom(point, 3);
```

I've tried migrating this to the following

```
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(52.6461049, 6.5583690);

var mapOptions = { 
   center: point, 
   zoom: 3, 
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmmap"), mapOptions);
```

The map is centered at the exact same location but the zoom is way off. Is there a difference between the zoom values in v2 and v3? Or did I migrate it the wrong way?

If I change 3 to 15, the zooming is about equal. But since I'm migrating a client environment, I want it to look exactly the same

Comment: This zooms the map the same amount as in my example code.

Comment: can you share your code here? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Unfortunately I can't make a working example because the google map api keys are bound by domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

V2 documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/introduction#LoadingMap
*Each map also contains a zoom level, which defines the resolution of the current view. Zoom levels between 0 (the lowest zoom level, in which the entire world can be seen on one map) to 19 (the highest zoom level, down to individual buildings) are possible within the normal maps view. Zoom levels vary depending on where in the world you're looking, as data in some parts of the globe is more defined than in others. Zoom levels up to 20 are possible within satellite view.*

V3 documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#MapOptions
*The initial resolution at which to display the map is set by the zoom property, where zoom 0 corresponds to a map of the Earth fully zoomed out, and higher zoom levels zoom in at a higher resolution.*

and also https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maxzoom?hl=en
 *Most roadmap imagery is available from zoom levels 0 to 18, for example.*

So they should be about the same.  Could it be something else wrong with  your code, e.g. are you doing fitBounds() anywhere or another method that could adjust the zoom level?

Comment: Hmm looks like the zoom 3 doesn't make any sense in the older version then, it works for some reason but I haven't got a clue why.

Comment: What is this `centerAndZoom` function? I don't see it listed on the V2 API documentation